# Field must be entered not shown

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a required field. It has two triggers:

- key next item
- when validate item

The built-in message `FRM-40202 - field must be entered` is not shown in status bar, but when I delete `key next item` trigger it is shown .

Please, explain to me why this happened and how can I solve this or - at least -  how to show the built in message .

thanks

Comment: It would certainly be helpful to know what code you have in the triggers, especially in the KEY-NEXT-ITEM trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check form's Property Palette, its "Validation Unit" property. What is it set to? Should be "Item" if you want that validation fires when you leave that *required* item.

Apart from that, `KEY-NEXT-ITEM` trigger is here for backward compatibility to Forms 3.0 which was the last version that used character mode, where there was no **mouse** involved (i.e. navigation was only through keyboard actions).

Nowadays, people use mouse and click *here* and click *there* to move through the form, so there's no guarantee that `KEY-NEXT-ITEM` will ever fire. Its code should be moved to `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM` which you already have. So, if both of them contain same code, and if you (as you said) deleted the `KEY-NEXT-ITEM` trigger, so be it. It is useless anyway.

Comment: thank you,i've changed the validation unit to item but same problem, the item behaves rightly i mean  I can't move to the next item until i enter a value but i need the normal built-in message to be shown to the user !!! when keep pressing enter key it stucks on the item until fill it with a value. the weird thing is that my item is a number type so when enter a character the built in message frm-50016 shown normally ,my problem ralated to required property i guess!

Comment: What does it mean that you "need the normal built-in message to be shown"? What is it, a "normal message"? The one that looks like a pop-up instead of a message in the status line? If so, see whether ON-ERROR and/or ON-MESSAGE triggers help. In there, you'd "capture" any error code you want and either use two consecutive MESSAGE calls, or use alerts (former is way simpler). There are examples in Forms Online Help System for those triggers, have a look.

Comment: i mean that why item validate correctly but not showing the usual frm-40202 on status bar ??

Comment: I wouldn't know.